# How do I do distinct union from 2 tables and insert data to a 3rd table - SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 3 tables

```
table1     country      countrytable  country     table2   country           
           UK                                              US
           Mexico                                          Mexico
```

table1 and table2 contain country data. `geogtable` has country column but no data

The data types for country in the 3 tables are the same

I would like the `countrytable` table to be populated as shown below:

**Countrytable**:

```
        country
        ----------
        US
        UK
        Mexico
```

I am not sure how to add the data to the `countrytable` columns

My attempt is

```
SELECT Country FROM table1
UNION
SELECT Country FROM table2
```

Comment: What problem are you having with your `union`?  Looks like it should produce the results you need.

Comment: Your query is fine for getting the distinct country list. What is the structure of geotable? Are you just having trouble writing the insert?

Comment: yes the insert into  countrytable  country column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `INSERT INTO .... SELECT` let your result insert to `countrytable` table.

```
INSERT INTO countrytable (country)
SELECT Country FROM table1
UNION
SELECT Country FROM table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
insert into countrytable
select country from  table1
union
select country from  table1
```